# python writing for loop result to csv

Tags: python, csv

I need to write my Python output to csv. Because of my limited Python knowledge, I am unable to write a functional code. 
Currently with each loop of the code, I print a line. And I would like to write the lines to each row of a csv file. This is what I have so far (my loop actually runs over 100 cas #'s, I am only attaching 2).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

url = "http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/united-states.html"
cas = ['50893-53-3','2094-98-6']

with open('name.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator = '\n',)
    for i in cas:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(url)

        inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Query")
        inputElement.send_keys(i)
        inputElement.submit()

        name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.name").text
        purity = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.applicationValue a").text
        catName = u" ".join((name, purity)).encode("utf-8")
        catName = catName.replace("(Sigma-Aldrich)" , "")
        catName = catName.replace("(Aldrich)" , "")
        catName = catName.replace("(Sigma)", "")
        print(catName)

        driver.quit()

        row = catName
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So what *does* your code do?

Comment: for each cas #, it prints a line of the chemical name

Comment: can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't understand the input to the csv writer. `writerow` is expecting a sequence representing the columns. You are combining the 2 values into a `catName` variable instead of passing them both to `writerow`. What's happening is that `writerow` is iterating over each item in the row, which in your case is a string, so it is splitting the string on each character.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

url = "http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/united-states.html"
cas = ['50893-53-3','2094-98-6']

with open('name.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator = '\n',)
    for i in cas:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(url)

        inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Query")
        inputElement.send_keys(i)
        inputElement.submit()

        name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.name").text.encode("utf-8")
        purity = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.applicationValue a").text.encode('utf-8')
        purity = purity.replace("(Sigma-Aldrich)" , "")
        purity = purity.replace("(Aldrich)" , "")
        purity = purity.replace("(Sigma)", "")
        print [name, purity]

        driver.quit()

        writer.writerow([name, purity])
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I am able to export the data to csv now. I have a question, for the second chemical, 1,1′-Azobis(cyclohexanecarbonitrile) 98%, why is it split into two columns? I suppose it's because of the comma, is there a way to remedy this? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? That comma is there from when you parsed out the text, it was not added by the csv writer. Also you have your csv writer set up to separate entries with tabs `\t` instead of commas so all of your results should yield 2 columns, the name and the purity.

Comment: I see. I copied the delimiter = '\t' and lineterminator = '\n' portions from some code that I found online. So this might be why I am getting weird results. I'll look into revising it. Thank you again for all your help!